# std::ifstream, use of deleted function

Tags: c++, function, ifstream, deleted-functions

I am trying to write a method which will get data from a `.txt` file.

I need to call this method from other methods. I have a problem with
passing arguments to methods.

Library.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Library
{
   std::vector<std::string> &mBooks;
   std::string books_list;
   std::string output;
   std::string books_path;

   void read_file(std::string &fn, std::ifstream &fn_var, std::string 
        &s, std::vector<std::string> &vn);
   void create_books_database(std::string &fn, std::ifstream,&fn_var,
        std::string &s, std::vector<std::string> &vn);
};
```

Library.cpp:

```
void Library::read_file(std::string &fn, std::ifstream &fn_var, 
std::string &s, std::vector<std::string> &vn)
{ 
    std::string &filename = fn;
    std::ifstream &name = fn_var;
    std::string &output = s;
    std::vector<std::string> &vector_name = vn;

    name.open(filename);

    if(!name)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Failed to open file "<<filename<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!name.eof())
    {
        std::getline(name, output);
        vector_name.push_back(output);
    }
}

void Library::create_books_database(std::string &fn, std::ifstream 
  &fn_var, std::string &s, std::vector<std::string> &vn)
{
    std::string books_path = fn;
    std::ifstream books_list = fn_var;
    std::string output = s;
    std::vector<std::string> mBooks = vn;

    read_file(books_path, books_list, output, mBooks);
}
```

Error:

```
src/Library.cpp: In member function ‘void                     
Library::create_books_database(std::__cxx11::string&, std::ifstream&, 
std::__cxx11::string&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> 
>&)’:
src/Library.cpp:35:32: error: use of deleted function 
‘std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const 
std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = 
std::char_traits<char>]’
 std::ifstream books_list = fn_var;
```

I think I messed a bit with references.

Comment: The variable names you use are anything but suggestive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `books_list` variable in `create_books_database()` is not declared as a reference. You are initializing one `std::ifstream` object with another, but `std::ifstream` has a deleted copy constructor so it can't be copied. That is what the error message is saying.

Change this:

```
std::ifstream books_list = fn_var;
```

To this:

```
std::ifstream &books_list = fn_var;
```

Or, simply get rid of the redundant local variables to begin with. There is no need to declare local reference variables to input parameters, all you are doing to creating extra aliases that don't really benefit anything. The parameters of `read_file()` are the same as the parameters of `create_books_database()` so just pass them as-is:

```
void Library::create_books_database(std::string &fn, std::ifstream &fn_var, std::string &s, std::vector<std::string> &vn)
{
    read_file(fn, fn_var, s, vn);
}
```